# Fully dynamic Stored SQL Procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

Is it possible to have **fully dynamic** SQL Stored procedures? I've read up on dynamic SQL for the past few hours but couldn't find the "fully dynamic" solution that I am looking for.

I want to make a procedure that allows for imports of all files of that type, just by simply passing the file location, table name, the rows data and value types. It shouldn't care how many columns there has to be, what datatypes are used etc.

Reason for this is that we are importing a lot of different types of .csv files, and having to make a new stored procedure and table for it sounds way more time consuming than just having to make the table and use a common procedure with some passed values.

Not a master of SQL, so I sketched out what I need in C# instead:

```
Table createAndFillTable(string tableName, string[] columnNames, string[] columnTypes, string[] rows)
{
    var t = CreateNewTable(tableName);
    for(int i = 0; i < columnNames; i++)
    {
        t.addColumn(columnNames[i], columnTypes[i]);
    }

    foreach(var r in rows)
    {
        //Needs parsing to correct data types
        t.AddRow(r);
    }

    return t;
}
```

The example is with creating new tables, but the optimal solution would be to just import to an existing table by passing 2 parameters, **tableName** and **fileLocation** and let the sql handle the variable types etc. No idea if that's a better solution though.

***Thanks up front!***

Comment: Why do you need dynamic SQL in the first place? Why have you tagged 2 completely different RDBMS.

Comment: @Larnu Got better ideas than dynamic SQL? The answer button is right below, I'll gladly hear it :)

Comment: Considering I came to this qusetion as you tagged SQL Server, and you have now removed that tag, I can no longer contribute.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I guess the sql-server tag was inappropriate

Comment: Why do you have to do this in sql? Why not just make a c# tool? It's a lot easier to put some intelligence there.

Comment: @HoneyBadger if I could I would, believe me.. Has to be sql..

Comment: Dynamic SQL is definitively possible since you have variables, string functions and [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#idm46064958709248). Of course, maintaining complex code inside strings means you can't benefit from any IDE feature (syntax highlighting, auto-completion, linting...) and syntax errors turn into runtime errors. Looks fun.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I would gladly do it in C# instead, but wouldn't that be a lot slower than bulk import when handling millions of rows of data every day?

Comment: You don't have to write anything at all - [bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does this already

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at bulk insert command line tool, it's designed for this scenario.
Also, consider dynamic sql instead of dynamic stored procedure.
You can use your C# to construct dynamic SQL statements that insert batches into the database.  A long time a go, stored procedures were compiled more efficiently, but for a long time that same type of compilation is applied to regular SQL Statements.

The bulk insert command line tool already takes care of the batching stuff which can be helpful.